# Error when using the IBackgroundCopyJob 2.SetCredentials method in Delphi (RAD Studio 10.3.3)

Tags: delphi, bit

I'm trying to use WinAPI BITS using the JEDI library. Everything seems to work out, but when I try to use the SetCredentials function, I have an error, it does not apply.. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong..

Below is the code how I'm trying to implement

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pJob: IBackgroundCopyJob;
  pJob2: IBackgroundCopyJob2;
  pJobID: TGUID;

  szUserName, szPassword: PWideChar;
  ac: BG_AUTH_CREDENTIALS;

  hr: HRESULT;
begin

  hr := bcm.CreateJob('testtask', BG_JOB_TYPE_UPLOAD, pJobID, pJob);

  if not Succeeded(hr) then
    raise Exception.Create('Create Job Failed');

  pJob.SetPriority(BG_JOB_PRIORITY_HIGH);
  pJob.SetNotifyInterface(Self);

  hr := pJob.AddFile(PWideChar('\\192.168.1.74\c$\test.mp4'),
    PWideChar('C:\test\test.mp4'));


  szUserName := PWideChar('contoso\jakonda');
  szPassword := PWideChar('Aa1234567');

  pJob2 := pJob as IBackgroundCopyJob2;

  ac.Target := BG_AUTH_TARGET_SERVER;
  ac.Scheme := BG_AUTH_SCHEME_NTLM;
  ac.Credentials.Basic.UserName := szUserName;
  ac.Credentials.Basic.Password := szPassword;

  hr := pJob2.SetCredentials(ac);

  if Succeeded(hr) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('S_OK');

  pJob.Resume;
```

Comment: "an error" just needs "a solution". Need something more specific? You first - what error and where?

Comment: sorry, i`m getting an error - The requested lookup key was not found in any active activation context.

Comment: I forgot add the info where.. The error occurs in hr := pJob2.SetCredentials(ac);